# Update for Facebook SDK for iOS v4.39.0

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am using cordova in my ionic app. For the Facebook functionality I am getting that "currently uses Facebook SDK for iOS v4.15.1, which relies on the recently deprecated Version 2.7 of the Graph API.

As a result, there is a risk that your app will no longer function if you don't upgrade to Facebook SDK for iOS v4.39.0.

As an admin of this app, please upgrade to the latest SDK as soon as possible to ensure your app's continued performance and to take advantage of new features."

But I am not using Facebook SDK, I am using openfb.js to login the user into the app.

Please confirm how I need to make sure that my app will run smoothly as I am not using this Faceboook SDK.

Here is the code which I am using in my App to use the Facebook functionality:

## Also the reference link for OpenFB : https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

$scope.fbLogin = function(){openFB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'});

```
        openFB.login(
                function(result1) {
                    if(result1.status === 'connected') {
                        var access_token = result1.authResponse.accessToken;
                        openFB.api({
        path: '/me',
        success: function(result) {
        var o = {};
        o.id=result.id;
        o.email = result.email;
        o.first_name = result.first_name;
        o.last_name = result.last_name;
        o.gender = result.gender;
        o.name = result.name;
            
             //Hitting some api to get the data
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: errorHandler});                       
                } else {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result1));                        
                }
                }, {scope: 'publish_actions, email, public_profile, user_friends'});            
                }
```

Comment: Can you provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @NinoFiliu edited above

Comment: @NinoFiliu Can you please help me in this.